# Scrollable Long Drop-down menu pushing content

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm tring to use this solution: http://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/ for scrollable Long Drop-down, but it's pushing the content down.

A way to reproduce it it's trying the source from the site, adding some

content at the end. You'll see that the menu will appear, moving the content aside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to: absolute (level one only)

```
/* LEVEL ONE */
ul.dropdown { position:  absolute; width: 100%; }
```